# Jquery if else statement skips

Tags: jquery

My if else statement only checks the first one?
Anyone knows why it does not check the rest of the conditions?-It skips the rest. I set up 3 variables to make writing the conditions easier. Below is HTML and JQUERY

```
<select id="tToth">
<option value="0">Select a state</option>
<option value="1">California</option>
<option value="2">Colorado</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select id="tState">
<option value="0">Select a Zone</option>
<option value="1">west</option>
<option value="2">sout</option>
<option value="3">east</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="boxa" size="6" required="required"></input>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="boxb" size="6" required="required"></input>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="boxb" size="6" required="required"></input>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" id="answerButton" value="Get Answer"></input> 

var plate = $("#tToth").val();
var bowl = $("#tState").val();
var emptyTextBoxes = $('input:text').filter(function () {
return this.value === "";
});
var string = "The blank textbox ids are - \n";

emptyTextBoxes.each(function () {
    string += "\n" + this.id;
});

if (emptyTextBoxes && plate && bowl) {
    alert("empty boxes and plate & bowl");
    $(".error").show();
} else if (emptyTextBoxes && !plate && !bowl) {
    alert("empty boxes, plate and bowl");
    $(".error").show();


} else if (!emptyTextBoxes && plate && !bowl) {
    alert("nothing empty");
    $(".error").show();

}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: And what do you mean is that `if` always executes, doesn't matter it is true or false.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what question you're asking, but there are several things wrong in how you're if/else tests are working so I'll explain those and perhaps that explains what is not working for you.

First off, `emptyTextBoxes` is a jQuery object and an object is always truthy.  That means that your last condition can never be met because `!emptyTextBoxes` will never be true.

If you want to test to see if the jQuery object is empty (e.g. has no DOM elements in it), then you check `emptyTextBoxes.length` instead.

So, fixing just that part of your if/else, you'd have this:

```
// if we have some emptyTextBoxes, but we do have values for plate and bowl
if (emptyTextBoxes.length && plate && bowl) {
    alert("empty boxes and plate & bowl");
    $(".error").show();
// if we have emptyTextBoxes, but no values for plate and bowl
} else if (emptyTextBoxes.length && !plate && !bowl) {
    alert("empty boxes, plate and bowl");
    $(".error").show();

// there are no empty text boxes, we have plate, but not bowl
} else if (!emptyTextBoxes.length && plate && !bowl) {
    alert("nothing empty");
    $(".error").show();

}
```

Beyond that, you may have a logic error because you have not covered all possible conditions and some conditions will match none of your conditions and it isn't clear that your tests are giving you the conditions you want.  I've added comments to each condition to illustrate what condition it is testing.

In particular, it appears that the last condition may never be met because if `plate` and `bowl` are `<input>` fields, then it's not possible to have zero `emptyTextBoxes`, but for `bowl` to be empty because if `bowl` was empty, then `emptyTextBoxes` would have something in it.

---

If you want further help sorting out the logic of these if/else conditions, then you will need to explain in words what you want each `if` condition to match and we can help with the proper logic for that.

---

Based on your further explanation, here's a version of code that checks each type of input upon click of the answer button:

```
$("#answerButton").click(function(e) {
    var plate = $("#tToth").val();
    var bowl = $("#tState").val();
    var emptyTextBoxes = $('input:text').filter(function () {
        return this.value === "";
    });
    if (plate === "0") {
        alert("Please select a State");
    } else if (bowl === "0") {
        alert("Please select a Zone");
    } else if (emptyTextBoxes.length !== 0) {
        alert("All text fields must contain a value")
    } else {
        alert("All values good");
    }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zhex1z4k/

Comment: I am trying to paste in the hTML but no luck.

Comment: I have 2 menus on the screen and multiple input boxes.  I just want to check when a getAnswer button is pressed if all fields have input && if all menus have a selection. Otherwise I want it to show an alert

Comment: @Vtienne - Use the "edit" link to put the HTML into your question where you can properly format it.  Multi-line code does not work in comments.

Comment: @Vtienne - your code runs immediately before the user has done anything in the page.  Therefore all inputs will be empty and both selects will be on their default value.  When do you want this code to run?  In addition, `plate` and `bowl` can be `"0"` which will still pass your `if` condition becausse it's a valid string.  You may have to check `plate !== "0"` and `bowl !== "0"`.

Comment: I want the code to run when the getAnswer button is clicked. So if the user puts anything in those fields or not…It needs to check. I had $("#getAnswer") in a button

Comment: @Vtienne - and please describe in words (in your question) what you want each condition of the `if/else` to match.

Comment: @Vtienne - I added code to my answer and a link to a working demo.  This should illustrate how to do your various checks and how to hook it up to a button click.  While this might not be exactly the checks you want (since you haven't described them in detail), you should be able to modify this as needed.

Comment: `code if (emptyTextBoxes && tState === "0" && tToth === "0") {
        alert("empty boxes and state, & month not select");
        $(".error").show();
    } else if (emptyTextBoxes && tState !== "0" && tToth === "0") {
        alert("only state selected");
        $(".error").show();
    } else if (!emptyTextBoxes && tState !== "0" && !tToth) {
        alert("nothing empty");code`

Comment: @Vtienne - since it looks like you are new here, do you know that if you get an answer that solves your problem, you can indicate that to the community by checking the green checkmark to the left of that answer.  This will earn both you and the person providing the answer some reputation points here on StackOverflow which can earn you more privileges.

Comment: Yes, new--I will get you a green check.. great job.. i was trying to copy in my code to show you my approach. Yours helped! well appreciated..i have been battling this for couple of days!

Comment: anyway to make this highlight the fields that are wrong by id?

Comment: @Vtienne - sure.  You have the DOM objects.  You know which ones contain invalid data.  Just add a class to the object to trigger a CSS style rule or set a specific CSS style on it.

Comment: So i don't need to place anything in an array?

Comment: @Vtienne - if you have an additional question about how to change styles to show invalid data, I'd suggest you start a new question and describe what you're trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use  if (!!your_variable). Because that will check if the variable is not undefined or null or empty.